# RedShift run multiple queries in parallel

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, etl

I have 20 ETL queries with multiple statements, i have to run all these scripts all in one go (or you can say in parallel) in RedShift. I'm doing the following:

I have created a main.sql file with the following content:

```
BEGIN;
query1.sql
query2.sql
...
COMMIT;
```

And i run this file as

```
 psql -h HOSTNAME -d mydb -U user -p PORT-a -q --single-transaction -f main.sql
```

But it runs the files sequentially. Is there a way to run these files in parallel?

Comment: One method is to put the code in separate files and to execute the `psql` command in the background.

Comment: it may be faster to run them sequentially BTW - thats the thing about MPP databases- 1 query can actually use 100% of the resource.

Comment: @Jon yes you are right.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i run 20 psql commands to run 20 ETL queries in background. But that would create 20 DB connections. And having multiple connections is different than running concurrent queries.

Comment: @AneelaSaleemRamzan . . . How are multiple connections different from running concurrent queries?

Comment: @gordon is it possible to run 20 queries in parallel in the same session instead of creating different connections?

Comment: I have defined a queue with 100% memory and concurrency level set to 15. When i run these 20 etl queries in parallel. Few queries have queue time greater than 0. How can i manage queues to have waiting time 0?